# Change position of icon drawable in TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, android-drawable

In my case, I have a textView with a drawable icon at the start of it(android:drawableStart), when the text of textView is multi-line, the icon goes in the vertical center of textView, but I want the icon to be aligned to the top of the text, how can I do this?
I don't want use any other layouts for doing this

[image: change_position_icon]

Answer (score 0):

There is [api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) to set the drawable, but first you should set the bounds .

Answer (score 0):

It is something different but a quick workaround.
Just use a `Checkbox` instead of a `TextView` and use `android:button` to define your drawable:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/..."
    android:gravity="top"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text=".."/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The approach I followed is to use `SpannableString` by setting a `Span` to the beginning of the string, being the `Spain` an `ImageSpain`

```
fun TextView.setDrawableAtStart(context: Context, textToSet: String?, @DrawableRes drawableRes: Int) {
if (textToSet.isNullOrBlank()) return

text = SpannableString(" $textToSet ").apply {
    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableRes) ?: return
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight)
    setSpan(
        ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),
        0, // Start position
        1, // End position
        Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
}
```

}

I encourage you to read [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568) interesting article about styling a text in Android.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` to set the drawable icons.

```
textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon), null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon_two), null);
```

As according to the **interface** you can see the position clearly and use accordingly to your need.

```
public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, 
                int top, 
                int right, 
                int bottom)
```

Comment: These arguments are resourceId's for drawabled to be used. They do not specify position